# Is it possible to get a single event's originalStart with Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with Microsoft's Graph API for Outlook calendar events, and I need to fetch the `originalStart` for exceptions to recurring events on a calendar.

When fetching events using the [List events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) function, I am provided with the events' original start dates, but when I grab a single event using the [Get event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) function, the object returned has no `originalStart`.

I do receive the event's `originalStartTimeZone` and `originalEndTimeZone`, but the original start date is simply missing.

The [event resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) lists this as a property for events, so I would expect it to be showing up. Any way to get this event without grabbing the entire list of events anew?

Answer (score 1):

I ve checked and confirm originalStart is missing or giving null value. You can look over there as the issue is already known : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4353

Comment: Thanks, I tried searching their issues and must have missed this somehow. I guess I'll have to wait on the issue to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get the originalStart by specifying it in the select query parameter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/<id>?$select=id,subject,originalStart
```